# What root CAs are trusted by Azure application gateway?

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to configure reverse proxying with an Azure application gateway, but it's complaining that the certificate being used by the backend is not trusted, despite being from a well known CA.
How can I tell which CAs the gateway trusts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the list of trusted CAs for application gateways here:
https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFT

In my case, the cert I was using was from Entrust, but the chain was not complete.
Consumer browsers have discovery capabilities to fully verify the authenticity chain, but the gateway requires you to provide the full chain yourself.

I just worked around it by trusting some self signed certs in the gateway, then having the gateway use the well known certs instead of using the well known certs on the backend and the gateway.